# How to download file from google drive using paperclip-googledrive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-drive-api

I have done file uploading on google drive but at the time of downloading got error:

```
ActionController::MissingFile: Cannot read file original_22_Wages372-817339(wages).pdf
```

I think it didn't get google drive path.

Attachment model:

```
has_attached_file :doc, 
  storage: :google_drive,
  google_drive_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/google_drive.yml",
  google_drive_options: {
    public_folder_id: '0BwCp_aK6VhiaQmh5TG9Qbm0zcDQ',
    path: proc { |style| "#{style}_#{id}_#{doc.original_filename}" }
  }
```

Controller:

```
 attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])      
 send_file attachment.doc.path(:original), 
   filename: attachment.doc_file_name, 
   type: attachment.doc_content_type, 
   stream: 'true', 
   x_sendfile: true
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: open(attachment.doc.url(:original)) using this could able to downloaded documents but some of document giving following bug . why ?Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - No picture from /home/kedar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dinesh, try the below code it will solve your problem.

```
    attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
    data = attachment.doc.url(:original)
    data = open(attachment.doc.url(:original))

    send_file data, filename: attachment.doc_file_name, 
      type: attachment.doc_content_type
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin . its very useful ans .

Answer (score 3):

You should read file first from your application. And then make it available for download.

```
attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id])
data = open(attachment.doc.url).read
send_file data, 
  :filename => attachment.doc_file_name, 
  type: attachment.doc_content_type, stream: 'true', 
  :x_sendfile => true
```

You can also make it available like :

```
redirect_to attachment.doc.url
```

But this is not a right way to do so. Because you directly opening your resources to end user.

Comment: Thanks for replying . but

data = open(attachment.doc.path(:original)).read

Above line has given following error

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - original_25_Muster_Roll372-817338(muster).pdf from /home/kedar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize'

Comment: Simply try find file from comsole. using `attachment.doc.url` Error says no such file. i.e. File missing. And id it return file properly then use `data = open(attachment.doc.url).read` instead

Comment: I uploaded file and I have checked file present in my google drive with same name ( original_25_Muster_Roll372-817338(muster).pdf) .

Comment: attachment.doc.url this line given me "no picture" error .

Comment: Check if this file `original_25_Muster_Roll372-817338(muster).pdf` is for same record ? Please check if this code `attachment.doc.url` returning any live url or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63343/discussion-between-nitin-verma-and-dinesh).

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0BwCp_aK6VhiaQmh5TG9Qbm0zcDQ/children?fields=items%2Fid&q=title+contains+%27original_25_Muster_Roll372-817338%28muster%29.pdf%27

Comment: You don't have public repository ? I am not able to open url you provided.

Comment: files folder are public in google drive but this url not able to open file (after login also) .I think this is wrong url but attachment.doc.url this line given me that returning url.

Comment: pls help me still i am trying.

Comment: open(attachment.doc.url(:original)) using this could able to downloaded documents but some of document giving following bug . why ?Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - No picture
from /home/kedar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize'

Comment: It is possibly a permission issue in your bucket

Comment: My all documents get uploaded but  get downloaded some documents . if permission issue then it will be same throughout all document (code is common for (download) all documents). attachment.doc.url(:original) this gives me proper url but when it open then cough the above error .this happen with some documents not for all .